# php header redirect not working

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-headers

I'm using an ajax call to trigger a php redirect using headers. According to chrome's developer tools the content of the page is loaded (ie: is in the resource list), but the page never redirects.

I'm not getting any error codes. Here's the php:

```
<?php  
ini_set('display_errors', false);  
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {  
  if($_POST['email']){  
    ...several calls to external db...  
    if(strlen($response->supporter->item->Email))
      //user is a member
      header('Location: http://www.example.com/page-one/');
    else
      header('Location: http://another-site.com/');
  }
}
?>
```

Nearly exactly the same code works in another part of the site. Any ideas why this is  pulling the correct content, but not loading it on the page?

the ajax call is:

```
$.post("http://www.our_site.org/is_member.php", { email: email });
```

Comment: Hold on, you are not fetching this using Ajax and expecting the header("location") to affect the parent page? Because that will never work.

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, so how would I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Switching to a js redirect worked perfect. Thanks Pekka!

Comment: Pekka, convert your comment to an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: I realized what my problem was after Pekka's comment - So "solved"

Answer (score 0):

Try That:

```
<?php  
ini_set('display_errors', false);  
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {  
  if($_POST['email']){  
    ...several calls to external db...  
    if(strlen($response->supporter->item->Email))
      //user is a member
      echo ('Location: http://www.example.com/page-one/');
    else
      echo ('Location: http://another-site.com/');
  }
}

?>
```

And inside of your js do that:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "http://www.our_site.org/is_member.php",
  data: {email: email },
  success: function(output){ window.location = output; }
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP do this? Where is the explanation?